# Why doesn't Magento 2.1 hint footer section?

Tags: magento-2.1, footer, template-hints

I'm learning magento 2. I enabled hints from admin panel .I try to find in root directory but have had no success. In my screenshot, My question is
why does magento not hint footer section? where is store footer section in magento root directory? Please suggest how it works?

Thanks.[image: ]]

Comment: No there is no static block found within this content and look there is not hints shown

Comment: Sorry my bad. What I mean is CMS Blocks not static block.

Comment: If you are using porto theme for magento 2. you should be able to find those cms block identifiers under porto settings. That's the reason why you are not seeing hints based on that screenshot. Because those portions are CMS Blocks.

Comment: yeah that right it store in cms_block table but how can it work.can you suggest?

Comment: Actually CMS Blocks by default in magento 2 it does not really show up in easypath hints. unless if you modify the xml layout of the footer and add your own phtml static blocks.

Comment: do you mean footer.phtml?

Comment: in footer.phtml  available code is <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links'); ?> please explain it.

Comment: I mean like you will add a custom block in default.xml. you can find it under Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

Comment: ok thank you very much for suggest.can you explain <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links'); ?>  what is "footer_links"? cause i have no block or widget with this name

Comment: https://webkul.com/blog/call-custom-block-links-footer-magento-2/ -- please also refer to this link.

Comment: <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links'); ?> what is "footer_links"?> -- This code is the standard coding in magento 2 to get or display the cms block name footer_links. you can find it on content>blocks> and find a cms block that has an identifier footer_links

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68315/discussion-between-ketty-and-mazestricks).